# Unidrectional OneToOne relationship SqlAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I'm trying to make a OneToOne relationship in SqlAlchemy, where the child's table ID is already the Foreign Key, but it is throwing me the error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance &lt;Vetor at 0x7fcc81307070&gt; is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

Below, the two models and the service..

```
class CUBE(types.UserDefinedType):
 def get_col_spec(self, **kw):
   return "CUBE"

class Vetor(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   data = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=db.func.now())
   vetor = db.Column(CUBE)
   sistema_origem_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
   
   def __init__(self, vetor, sistema_origem):
       self.vetor = vetor
       self.sistema_origem_id = sistema_origem
       
   def __repr__(self):
       return "<Vetor(id='%s', data='%s', vetor='%s', sistema_origem_id='%s')>" % (self.id, self.data, self.vetor, self.sistema_origem_id)
```

```
class FBinary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("vetor.id"), primary_key=True)
    binario = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    contenttype = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self, id, binario, contenttype):
        self.id = id
        self.binario = binario
        self.contenttype = contenttype
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<FBinary(id='%s', binario='%s', contentype='%s')>" % (self.id, self.binario, self.contenttype)
```

The class that tries to commit both:

```
    ....code.....

    face = Vetor(vetor, 1 ) 
    db.session.add(face)

    binario = FBinary(id=face, binario=foto_bytes, contenttype='')
    db.session.add(binario)

    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your error. That being said, a possible solution should be:

```py
    face = Vetor(vetor, 1 ) 
    db.session.add(face)
    db.session.comit()  # Now your database has an entry in Table vetor with id 1

    binario = FBinary(id=face.id, binario=foto_bytes, contenttype='')  # reference the id from your face object.
    db.session.add(binario)
    db.session.commit()
```

I assumed that vetor is some kind of data and **not a Vetor object** (why would you try to save a Vetor object in the vetor table?).

Hope that helps. Please consider to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your next question.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. It is for face recognition. I'm using this API https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/, this would be the 'register face' api.I need to save the data in a 'CUBE' column (PG extension). (it wil be better for comparison when trying to recognize the face, I can do the comparison through the query). The 'vetor' are biometric data, something like `(-0.137929931282997131, 0.0440808013081550598, 0.0179916676133871178,....)`. However it is not the problem, I can save the face without any problem, if I don't add the binary to the session `db.session.add(binario)`

Comment: Doing as you said it not the ideal, since I would have to commit the Face(Vetor table), and there will be many other relationships related, that I would need to rollback if something goes wrong.